# Wrong argument type for 'sizes' in argument bundle. string[] expected

Tags: kotlin, serialization

The received stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'sizes' in argument bundle. string[] expected.
>      at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.addInDefaultArgs(NavDestination.java:524)
>      at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:932)
>      at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:867)
>      at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:804)
>      at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:790)
>      at com.example.kotinmvvm.adapter.UserAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(UserAdapter.kt:51)

The code in User.kt:

```
class User {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: String = ""

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String = ""

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    var image: String = ""

    @SerializedName("desc")
    @Expose
    var desc: String = ""

    @SerializedName("sizes")
    @Expose
    val sizes = ArrayList<String>()
}
```

The JSON data:

```
{
id: 43354,
desc: "Nobis voluptatibus est necessitatibus tempore voluptate voluptatibus. Illum suscipit nam et nostrum. Est exercitationem tempore pariatur nisi soluta iure.",
name: "Prof. Carmel Ebert III",
image: "https://lorempixel.com/640/640/?81469",
sizes: [
"UK7",
"UK8",
"UK9",
"UK10"
]}
```

What changes are necessary to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to tell without having seen the JSON.

That probably should be:

```
val sizes: ArrayList<String>()
```

or try:

```
var sizes: String = ""
```

Comment: {
id: 43354,
desc: "Nobis voluptatibus est necessitatibus tempore voluptate voluptatibus. Illum suscipit nam et nostrum. Est exercitationem tempore pariatur nisi soluta iure.",
name: "Prof. Carmel Ebert III",
image: "https://lorempixel.com/640/640/?81469",
sizes: [
"UK7",
"UK8",
"UK9",
"UK10"
]}

Comment: I have updated the post with JSON . please have a look

Comment: I am facing the similar issue, could you get the solution. Please post here if yes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the inner list of string object change try

```
  @SerializedName("sizes")
  @Expose
  var sizes : List<String>? = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this class

```
data class User(
    @SerializedName("desc")
    var desc: String = "",
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("image")
    var image: String = "",
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String = "",
    @SerializedName("sizes")
    var sizes: List<String> = listOf()
)
```

You can easily convert any JSON data to data class using this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-)

Comment: thanx . I will try

Comment: Let me know, if you face any issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to put a null value in a bundle object which was used to pass to the next fragment using navigation component library.

```
  val bundle = Bundle()
  bundle.putString(
     KEY,
     value
 )
```

The value above was null actually. `putString()` was accepting it at compile time but then it threw the error during run time

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'KEY' in argument