# How to get each item from the array?

Tags: kotlin

I have:

```
sizes = ["UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10"]
```

I have tried:

```
val listSizes= sizes?.split(",").toTypedArray()
```

listSizes is just `[]`.  Why?

Comment: Why don't you use arrayOf ?

Comment: in which language do you have `sizes = ["UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10"]`? is this Javascript? something similar in Kotlin would probably rather be just `sizes = arrayOf("UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10")` or if it is a string, then `sizes = """["UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10"]"""`... which of those is it?

Comment: Note that if you say "listSizes is just `[]`" it actually is an empty array (printed via `Any.toString()`)... reason for it: `sizes` was probably already an array (just a guess)... so you can't split by `","` as that is the delimiter within your code, not within a string...

Comment: ok... I saw your other question now: [Wrong argument type for 'sizes' in argument bundle. string\[\] expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073133/wrong-argument-type-for-sizes-in-argument-bundle-string-expected) ... so basically it is still that problem... you do not want to write your own JSON-parser... for me this question here doesn't really make sense, if the other question isn't yet solved for you...

Comment: thanx everyone . I have found another solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try -

```
val sizes = listOf("UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10");
val listSizes= sizes.toTypedArray();
println(listSizes.contentToString()); //[UK7, UK8, UK9, UK10]
```

`sizes` is already a list of strings. You would need to `split` by comma only if you were trying to break a string *containing* commas (like `"UK7, UK8, UK9"`).

Also, alternatively, you could use `arrayOf()`-

```
val listSizesArray = arrayOf("UK7","UK8","UK9","UK10");
println(listSizesArray.contentToString()); //[UK7, UK8, UK9, UK10]
```